# smaller numbers than a given r

Tags: c, string, numbers

The code is working just when `r` is smaller than `1` (ex: `0.99`), but if `r = 1` nothing appears:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int nr = 2;
    float x1 = 0, x2 = 0, nextTerm = 0, r;

    scanf("%f", &r);

    while (nextTerm < r) {
        nextTerm = (1 + x2 + x1 * x1) / 3;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = nextTerm;
        nr++;
    }
    printf("%d", nr);

    return 0;
}
```

The code is working just when `r` is smaller than `1` (ex: `0.99`), but if `r = 1` nothing appears

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the code supposed to do, exactly? What output are you expecting? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Did you debug and check variables contents ?

Comment: If nothing appears that means you enter un infinite loop. Try printing nextTerm value inside the loop.

Comment: Try printing the value of `nextTerm` each time through the loop to see the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

When you set a number greater than or equals to 1 while you are looping validated by a division of numbers smaller than 1, you are basically dividing a number smaller than 1 by a greater one (3, in the `(1 + x2 + x1 * x1) / 3;`), so you'll never get a number greater than 1 to stop the loop. Because no matter what you put in the prompt, if the values of x1 and x2 are smaller than 3 you'll never get a number greater than 1.